# How do you nest two of Polymer's firebase-collection elements inside dom-repeat?

Tags: data-binding, firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer

I have a problem of looping two of Polymers firebase-collection elements.
With my database structure i first have to check which events the user has access to, then get the information on that event from events.

The problem with this code is that when i loop the second firebase-collection the data-binding on "events" will be the same on all that repeats and therefore it will be the same name on every h4.

So is there a way of having a unique variable in data="{{ }}". 
or is there a better way of writing out the data?

```
<firebase-collection data="{{userData}}" location="{{_getCorrectUrl()}}"></firebase-collection> 
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{userData}}" as="user">
  <firebase-collection data="{{events}}" location="{{_getCorrectEventsUrl(user.__firebaseKey__)}}" ></firebase-collection> 
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{events}}" as="event">
    <h4>{{event.value.name}}</h4>
  </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you not load the user with the events so you don't have to do the second `firebase-collection` and could just repeat over `{{userData.events}}`?

Comment: That will solve the problem but it will make it slower. I'm following firebases recommendations https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Comment: did you get to solve this problem?

Comment: Think I'm reading the documentation that you can't use permissions as a filter.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution which I consider not the best way to solve this issue, but it works for me. I created another element called 'my-user, I exposed an attribute called user which is assigned the value of user from the first dom-repeat. Everything works, however, I am not satisfied with this solution. I am still looking for a solution which doesn't involve creating a dedicated element for that.

```
<firebase-collection data="{{userData}}" location="{{_getCorrectUrl()}}">
</firebase-collection> 
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{userData}}" as="user">
  <my-user user="[[user]]"></my-user>
</template>
```

and the other 'my-user':

```
<dom-module id="my-user">
<template>
  <firebase-collection data="{{events}}" location="{{_getCorrectEventsUrl(user)}}" ></firebase-collection> 
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{events}}" as="event">
    <h4>{{event.value.name}}</h4>
  </template>
</template>
<script>
    (function () {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-user',
    _getCorrectEventsUrl: function(obj) {
      return 'https://app.firebaseio.com/users/' + obj.__firebaseKey__;
    },
    properties: {
      user:{
        type:Object,
      },
    },

  });
})();
</script>
</dom-module>
```

**EDIT**

Now after sometime of answering this question I came to realize that when someone face such a situation with NoSQL database, it usually highlights a problem in the design. Data should be de-normalized and one should avoid joining like what is normally done in SQL databases. Watch the The [Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=6) on youtube.

Comment: Did you get any better solution than this? or still using the same solution of having another custom element.

Comment: @Srikanth yes, watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8&index=3&list=PLNYkxOF6rcICdISJclfQhj2S8QZGjXV8J
you basically need to redesign your application.